# JupyterHub Not Loading Up with Given External-IP| K8s | Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, jupyterhub

I have a bare metal setup with MetalLB and nfs-subdir via helm ([source](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner)). I am using k8s v1.20.5 with one master and two worker nodes. I installed JupyterHub with Helm, setting the secretkey and readjusted the allocated volume. On run, the pods look fine but when I use the external-ip to run JupyterHub the page keeps loading infinitely. I have done the following:

```
kubectl describe pods <name of the jupyterHub pod>
```

which gives me:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  17m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/hub-6d785f96b5-xs7pr to worker-2
  Normal  Pulled     17m   kubelet            Container image "jupyterhub/k8s-hub:1.2.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    17m   kubelet            Created container hub
  Normal  Started    17m   kubelet            Started container hub
```

The volume is also being created on the nfs store and on deleting the jupyterhub pod it is being archived. So that is working fine (I guess). I have created nginx deployment with helm and that works fine. The jupyterHub external-ip however, keeps loading infinitely with no errors.

Any help on how to solve this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question was originally raised in a GitHub issue, then on Jupyter's discourse, and now here. I'll respond in https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterhub-not-launching-on-helm-k8s/11901 and suggest everyone looking to help focus discussion there.